# Why was my flag on an obsolete "add this tag" comment declined?

Tags: discussion, flagging, comments

[This comment](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/223577/did-darth-vader-ever-operate-a-button-on-the-devices-on-his-belt-or-his-chest#comment611591_223577)  on the *Star Wars* question [Did Darth Vader ever operate a button on the devices on his belt or his chest?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/223577/58193) reads:

> If canon isn't an issue for an answer, you should add the star-wars-legends tag

A couple of hours ago the OP must have seen this comment and added the tag. On seeing the edit, I opened up the question and saw the now obsolete comment and so I flagged it as "No longer needed". To my surprise this flag was declined with no message.

I proceeded to re-flag it with a custom reason assuming it was either a mistake on the mods' behalf or I was completely overlooking something.

> The question *has* the Legends tag added by the OP therefore a comment saying you should add it is no longer needed. (flagging again with an explanation as the last flag was declined, don't know why).

Again to my surprise it was declined and again it was declined with no message leaving me completely in the dark as to *why* it was declined.

Now, as far as I can tell a comment about adding a tag becomes obsolete once the tag has already been added so I can't work out why my flags were declined and the comment not deleted.

**Why were my flags declined?**

Answer (score 4):

Because there's an [ongoing meta discussion](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/12815/31394) concerning the canonicity expected of answers to that question, and I didn't think it was wise to sweep any pertinent information under the rug.

The existence of a [star-wars-legends](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/star-wars-legends) tag on a question is highly relevant, as far as I understand, to the expected canon level of answers thereto. And the OP is a new contributor, so just from an edit it might not be clear if they really intended to change the scope of the question or not. **Having the information as to what inspired them to retag the question and why**, available to everyone and not just mods, may be important for the other meta discussion. And there's **certainly no harm** in leaving an extra comment on the question.

---

Sorry about not giving any reason for the decline. Unfortunately, for comment flags, there's only a "delete" button and a "decline" button, and **no possibility to give extra feedback**. [I'm hoping that may change](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/337731/278659), but for now it's impossible for mods to explain in the flag response *why* a comment flag was declined.

Comment: I don't really agree with the reasons for declining but thanks for at least explaining. And I didn't know you couldn't give reasons on declining comment flags (or had forgotten that it wasn't possible).

Comment: This was a case where I'd really have liked to explain the decline, or even mark the flag helpful but not delete the comment. But yeah, comment flag options :-/